# AOP AfterThrowing Advice called in Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-aop

**Description**

I have a unit test for which I do not want the AOP to be loaded. I don't load the AOP in any of the unit test code. The classes which are not mocked do not have any AOP/beans/components autowired and or used.

On running the unit test the code is suppose to throw a custom exception called FrameworkException.

However the AOP catches the exception and runs the AfterThrowing Advice. I don't want this in the unit test.

Can anyone help?

**The Problem**

Why is the ExceptionAspect afterThrowing() advice still being called? It was not called previously.

**Suspicions**

Does mock code still instantiate with any existing functionality?

**Attempted resolutions**
- I have tried loading an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext which loads an empty configuration class. This did not seem to work.

**Code Example - Unit Test**

```
@Test
public void processRequest_WithRequestParameterNull_ExceptionExpected()
{
    try
    {
        RequestWrapper requestMock = Mockito.mock(RequestWrapper.class);
        Auditor auditorMock = Mockito.mock(Auditor.class);
        CoreWrapper coreMock = Mockito.mock(CoreWrapper.class);

        RequestAssessmentStatusHandler handler = new RequestAssessmentStatusHandler(requestMock, auditorMock,
                coreMock);
        handler.processRequest(null);
        fail("processRequest_WithRequestParameterNull_ExceptionExpected failed.");
    }
    catch (FrameworkException e)
    {
        assertEquals(EventIds.INVALID_FRAMEWORK_PARAMETER, e.getEventId());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        fail("processRequest_WithRequestParameterNull_ExceptionExpected unhandled exception: "
                + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}
```

**Code Example - AfterThrowing Advice**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ExceptionAspect
{
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *(..))", throwing = "exception")
    public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) throws Exception
    {
        // Do things here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Which aspects weaving method do you use? It seems you code compiled code (.class) is already enhanced with aspects and therefor your unit test which just uses your pure RequestAssessmentStatusHandler class (without Spring context) calls code from aspect. Maybe you could switch it to weaving aspects when class is loaded using classloader at runtime?

Comment: @Szpak How do I do what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You could add @Profile("!test") to your aspect component and then add @ActiveProfiles("test") annotation to your test.